# Copying files from APFS to Mac OS Extended too slow

Tags: copy-paste, apfs

I'm using NVME SSD (APFS) as my main boot drive. I also have USB 3 External SSD (Mac OS Extended Journal).

I just tried to copy 40GB files from APFS to mac OS Extended and it took 15 mins. It's painfully slow. It's almost slower than coping files to my NAS.

Is this expected with APFS?

Comment: How much free space on the external SSD?

Comment: @Mark it has more than 50% (250GB+)